# How to validate XHR Header information?

Tags: ruby, ajax, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

I am testing a regression test suite manually. In that, I am validation various `xmlHTTPrequests` header information.

As of now I am using `Chrome Developer Tools` to inspect the web traffic but it seem like it's taking too long to test the suite manually. I want to automate that. I am a new to `AJAX` & really don't know what are the libraries available to do that.

I want to get all the `XHR Payload` information & store it into some format like `JSON`.

Is there any `ruby gem` available to do that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I have a host [www.shopstyle.com](http://www.shopstyle.com)  Now, I have a regression test plan in which I have to validate `Request Headers` `Response Headers` & `Request Payload` manually everytime. Currently, I am using Chrome Dev Tools--> Network utility. So, I am trying to develop a proxy script which will trace all HTTP requests & give me `Request Headers` `Response Headers` & `Request Payload` for particular filter. I have researched on `mechanize` & `HTTParty` gem but both are not giving appropriate o/ps acc to my application.